# reset or customize index to change order of list DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi, powerquery

Need help with the following if statement for PowerBI

```
if [#"# Lives Range"] = "0-100" then 1 
else 
if [#"# Lives Range"] = "101-500" then 2 
else 
if [#"# Lives Range"] = "501-3000" then 3 
else 
if [#"# Lives Range"] = "3000+" then 4 
else 
if [#"# Lives Range"] = "New" then 5 
else 
if [#"# Lives Range"] = "Runout" then 6
```

Trying to create a unique Index to place the list in correct order - due to the 3000+ value does not place it correctly in ascending order.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: In your other recent thread you learned you were using M (Power Query) not DAX. Which is it here?

Comment: I am still new to Power BI - I am designing in Power BI Desktop, which everone is used with this tool.

     SWITCH([lives range],"0-100",1,"101-500",2,"501-3000",3,"3000+",​    4,"New",5,"Runout",6)
    
Here is my latest attempt - however, for some reson it does not like the "3000+", 4,  portion of the statement.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not like"? Do you get an error?

Comment: thanks for your input, however, I was able to figure it out:

     if [live range]="0-100" then 1 else(
     if [live range]="101-500" then 2 else(
     if [live range]="501-3000" then 3 else(
     if [live range]="3000+" then 4 else(
     if [live range]="New" then 5 else(
     if [live range]="Runout" then 6 else 999)))))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your input, however, I was able to figure it out:

```
 if [live range]="0-100" then 1 
 else( if [live range]="101-500" then 2 
 else( if [live range]="501-3000" then 3 
 else( if [live range]="3000+" then 4 
 else( if [live range]="New" then 5 
 else( if [live range]="Runout" then 6 
 else 999)))))
```

Thanks. – Karen yesterday